# How to print a statement if you receive a KeyError?

Tags: python

Let's say I'm defining a variable X. And X is going to be based on a user's input. Then I search a dataframe's columns based on the value of X. The user may enter a value for X that is not within the dataframe's columns and the code will return a KeyError. Instead of receiving a key error, I would like to print a statement, and then just continue with the rest of the code. Is this possible?

Comment: `try/except` statements is what you are looking for, https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions

Comment: Yes, it is possible. It's called *exception handling*. Have a look at `try`, `except`, and `finally` keywords in Python. You will find your answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
try:
    custom_db_lookup()
    #your look up code here
except KeyError as err: # Only accept error's that are KeyError
    print(err) #The exception we captured
    print("Couldn't find that")
```